# Android - How to create a folder that can't be accessed by user?

Tags: android, file-storage

I have created a file inside one folder in android and I have encrypted that file. When user clicks "READ" button in my app, the specified file will be decrypted in same folder. but I want the users not to access those files via USB or file manager. How to implement this concept?

Comment: you can use internal memory

Comment: use app data internal memory. Only root users can access it. But in general, you shouldn't expect that users win't be able to access some files. If I want, I will find a way to access the file.

Comment: @RishabhMahatha am using internal memory only

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
context.getDir(null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In place of

```
context.getExternalCacheDir()
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks ... let me check it.